# Android Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) error in ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, fatal-error, sigabrt

I have a long list(2K or more) to show in a ListView. I am using an arraylist for the list. It is running well initially. When I am scrolling down the list continuously, it is throwing fatal signal, **libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000053cd (code=-6), thread 21453** and the activity gets crashed. I have checked that there is no problem to hold the the arraylist, the system can hold 5-6k data also, but on scrolling down, it got crashed after 1.5-2k data. What may be the possible reason and fix for it?

Comment: Would you consider posting some of your code? Maybe there is a memory leak inside the view recycling logic in your ListView's Adapter.

Comment: Did you try to run the app in different devices and different Android versions? Does the error happen in emulator?

Comment: I have tried it in different tab and also in Nexus 5. It is happening all of them.

Comment: Please anyone help on this?